# Can laser-induced graphene wires produce electromagnetic fields if a current is passed through them?

Tags: electromagnetism, materials, electromagnet, lithography

For those who don't know, [laser-induced graphene (LIG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene_production_techniques#Laser-Induced_Graphene_(LIG)) is a porous type of graphene that appears after exposing certain types of carbon-based materials with a laser.

In [this video](https://youtu.be/RKcUgdXUf9Y), they made LIG on Kapton tape using a cheap 400 nanometer laser engraver module. He used the LIG to make supercapacitors, not to make conductive wires. At the end he used the LIG to make a low-voltage heater.

If I took a Kapton wire, turned it into a LIG wire, used the wire to make a coil and passed an electrial current (a DC current), would it generate an electromagnetic field?

Comment: A current flow produces a magnetic field, regardless of medium, including no apparent medium at all (as in vacuum: a propagating wave)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current through the coil will produce a magnetic field. The voltage across the coil that pushes the current through the coil will produce an electric field.